# How to get object (self) generic type in extension swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am making am function to convert a Set to an array using extension to Set. But I am not able to get generic type of Set in that extension. For example if there is an object of Set of type String then toArray() function should return an array of String  ( [String] ). I am creating this function like this.

```swift
extension Set{
    func toArray() -> [/*What type should take*/]{
        var array = [/*What type should take*/]()
        for s in self{
            array.append(s)
        }
        return array
    }
}

// Here is what I am expecting from the above func.
var myset = Set<String>()
let arr = myset.toArray() // Should return [String]
```

Comment: What is wrong with `let arr = Array(myset)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was simple use `Element` to get its Generic type

```swift
extension Set{
    func toArray() -> [Element]{
        var array = [Element]()
        for s in self{
            array.append(s)
        }
        return array
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Element` to get the element type, however there is no real need for this extension as you can simply say `let arr = Array(mySet)`

If you did want to use the extension you can simplify it to:

```
extension Set {
    func toArray() -> [Element] {
        return Array(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes @Paulw11 I know about `Array(set_obj)` I asked this in context of toArray for simplicity I need Generic type for different purpose. Thank you